# Salesforce matrix report

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-reports, format, report-formula

Hi I am trying to create a salesforce report to show the 3 columns

1. Contact owner
2. number of contacts per owner
3. whether contacts have any activity on them or not(sum of relation)

My report looks something like below but I want to show just the number of contacts per user not the name of the contacts, could someone please help me to achieve the numbers instead of names?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck the details rows option and group by Contact Owner in the report and run it.  Refer to the image below and see the options available at the end.

The best place to learn about reports and dashboard is Trailhead. Learn more about grouping here:- [Group and Categorize Your Data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/create-reports-and-dashboards-for-sales-and-marketing-managers/group-and-categorize-your-data)

[image]

If you want to show the columns with the count, then check the details rows only and it will appear as follows:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Sanket, this way I get only 2 columns but I want all 3 of them

Comment: @gs650x find the update in my answer

Comment: Thank you again, but this still doesn't serve the purpose

Comment: The third field is some of the relation count which shows the number of activities per contact. The first name,last name and created date is not required 
I just want 3 fields contact owner, number of contact per owner and number of activities per contact